# unable to add a custom field as a href on a button that is being injected as function

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm having an issue when I try to add a custom field file as a href download on a button that I am injecting to a wordpress website using a function.

```js
function inject_link_into_post_feed() {
    // Output the <a> tag inside the "item-main" div
    echo '<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var fileLink = "'.get_field('file_link').'";
                var downloadLink = $("<a>").attr({
                    "href": fileLink,
                    "download": "true"
                }).text("Download Guide");
                $(".books-feed .item-main").append(downloadLink);
            });
        </script>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'inject_link_into_post_feed');
```

The code pulls in the button to the specific piece of html, but the download link from the custom field does not appear to work.

Here is the link to the website the download button is pulling through to. you can see this in the post cards.

https://thirst.io/guides/

Please would someone be able to advise me on where I am going wrong with the code I have written for the custom field to not pull through.

Comment: So the issue is `get_field('file_link')` is empty, correct?

Comment: The code is PHP for the functions file, but there were no options for me to add PHP.

Correct. The file link does not pull through on the front-end of the website if you inspect the code the href is empty. @RobEyre